# How to add else statement into downloading code?

Tags: vb.net, download

I'm making a file downloader and I want it to download files to either my selected directoy or default directory.

Downloading code is here:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Button1.Enabled = False
    Button1.Text = "Updating..."
    WebBrowser1.Visible = True

    Dim uri As System.Uri = New System.Uri("http://199.91.154.170/e9f6poiwfocg/pei02c8727sa720/Ultra+v08.zip")
    Dim webclient As System.Net.WebClient = New System.Net.WebClient()

    Dim path As String = 
            If apppath = Nothing then
                New String(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "test\\Test.zip"))
            Else New String
                (apppath)
            End if

    Dim fileInfo As System.IO.FileInfo = New System.IO.FileInfo(path)
    If Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(fileInfo.Directory.FullName) Then
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(fileInfo.Directory.FullName)
    End If

    AddHandler webclient.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf webclient_DownloadDataCompleted

    webclient.DownloadFileAsync(uri, path)

End Sub
Private Sub
```

And user selected path apppath is defined here:

```
If apppath = "" Then
        Dim dialog As New FolderBrowserDialog()
        dialog.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop
        dialog.SelectedPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath( _
        Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData))
        dialog.Description = "Select directory where to install the files"
        If dialog.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            apppath = dialog.SelectedPath
        End If
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(apppath & " apppath.txt", apppath, False)
    End If
```

How to fix Dim path As String else statement?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly then I believe there is a simple solution, which is this:

```
Dim path As String
If apppath = Nothing then
    path = New String(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "test\Test.zip"))
Else New String
    path = apppath
End if
```

If I have not understood your requirements correctly, then please provide more information.

Comment: Cleared out ton of errors but still remains Syntax error on Else New String and 'Combine' is not a member of 'String'

Comment: @Kaur Palang, I have edited the code in my answer (I don't think you have to escape the forward slash).  If this produces an error, then let me know what the error is.

Comment: Full code is here: http://pastebin.com/RTYzZJLA
Syntax error is on line 20
'Combine' is not part of 'String' is on line 57

Comment: Combine is not a property of the String class (this is how you are treating it in your link on line 57).  Remove 'Path.' on line 57 so it says: dialog.SelectedPath = Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData))

Comment: There is no constructor in the String class that accepts zero arguments.  You initialize the path variable on line 21.  Therefore remove 'New String' on line 20.

Comment: How/where to insert Argument(Null)Exeptions?

Comment: @Kaur Palang, I have answered your original question.  You are now asking another question i.e. the question in your last comment has nothing to do with the original question.  Please mark this question as answered (if it has helped you) and ask another question in a new thread.

Comment: I have no more errors, but if I run the program, and press the Button3 to set apppath, I get unhandled exception.

Comment: You will have to wrap the code in a Try/Catch statement as explained here: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/net/nets5p4.html.  There is a bug.